# How can configure Docker so that a user may only stop the containers they started?

Tags: docker, permissions

On my computer (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64), 
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24), if user A launches a container (`docker run`), user B may stop it (`docker stop`) .

How can configure Docker so that a user may only stop the containers they started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in docker. This is because docker containers by nature run as root. This means that someone could deploy a container where they have root access, give themselves access to the host environment through volume maps, and *bam*, they have root access on the host.

If you want to have multiple users have docker environments, and they should be segregated, you will either have to roll-your-own solution for this (that involves not giving access to the docker machine OR containers via command line), or you will need to have multiple machines (one per user) that they can be segregated to.

Here is a good article on docker root escalation: http://container-solutions.com/docker-security-admin-controls-2/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20180528053035/http://container-solutions.com/docker-security-admin-controls-2/)).

Comment: Thanks. "you will need to have multiple machines (one per user) that they can be segregated to." -> do you mean multiple computers?

Comment: Yes, or multiple virtual machines on the same computer. You can simulate this on your local machine by using a virtualmachine (check out VirtualBox with Vagrant to get started easily)

Answer (score 2):

By exposing the Docker CLI to a user by adding the user to the docker usergroup or make him an admin user, he can create, remove and kill containers. He can even change the configuration of the Docker deamon.

If CLI access is not required, you can change this by deny access for all users except the admin user.

User management can managed by using solutions as [portainer](https://portainer.io%20%E2%80%9CPortainer%E2%80%9D) or [docker ucp](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/)